# argparse add_argument from dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I have the following dictionary I'm am trying to use to generate arguments in argparse:

```
inititateCmdMap = {
    '-l': {
        'help': 'list of transactions for type',
        'choices': ['all', 'utxq', 'mtxq']},
    '-u': {
        'help', 'url of rest server'},
    '-k': {
        'help': 'something helpful'},
    '-x': {
        'help': 'expression'}}
```

But I'm not sure how to pass it as the following excepts:

```
[parser.add_argument(v[0], v[1]) for v in inititateCmdMap.items()]

 in add_argument
    kwargs = self._get_optional_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.4_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/argparse.py", line 1446, in _get_optional_kwargs
    if not option_string[0] in self.prefix_chars:
KeyError: 0
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've been passing the dict itself, instead of unpacking its contents.

Try like this:

```
for arg, kwargs in inititateCmdMap.items():
    parser.add_argument(arg, **kwargs):
```

Comment: now I get `TypeError: add_argument() argument after ** must be a mapping, not set`

Comment: The options you have for `-u` is a set `{'help', 'url of rest server'}` but it should be a dict `{'help': 'url of rest server'}`